# HTML (ASP.NET) div rendered inside previous div rather than after it

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the following in an aspx file:

```
...
 <div class="graybg">
    <div id="clmn1">
       <div class="title2">Pick Up From:</div>
       <div id="pickup_options" class="selservice" runat="server">
          <div class="boxes">
             <asp:ImageButton class="box1" src="./box1.png" runat="server" OnClick="OnClickAddress" alt="Ground Address" />
             <div class="boxtitle">Ground Address</div>
          </div>
          <div class="boxes">
             <asp:ImageButton class="box1" src="./box2.png" runat="server" OnClick="OnClickAirport" alt="Airport" />
             <div class="boxtitle">Airport</div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div id="pickup_airport" runat="server">
          <div class="rows">
             <div class="inputbtnholder">
                <asp:TextBox class="input1" ID="TextBox1" placeholder="Enter Flight Number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <div id="Div1_pkup" class="imgbtn searchbtn"></div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="rows">
             <asp:TextBox class="input1 martop" ID="TextBox2" placeholder="Airport" runat="server" />
             <div id="airport_search" class="imgbtn searchbtn" />
          </div>
          <div class="rows">
          <div class="inputbtnholder">
          <script type="text/javascript"> ...
          <asp:TextBox ID="pickupdatetime" class="input1 martop" placeholder="Select Date and Time" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          <div id="Div2_pkup" class="imgbtn datebtn"></div>
          </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div id="pickup_ground" runat="server">
          <div class="inphld">
             <asp:TextBox class="input1" ID="address" placeholder="Search for address" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             <div id="searchbtn" class="imgbtn searchbtn"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="inphld">
             <asp:TextBox class="input1 martop" ID="pickupdate" placeholder="Select Date and Time" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
              <div id="datebtn" class="imgbtn datebtn"></div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="selservice">
....
```

All my indentation matching inspections (manual and automatic) tell me that the div of class selservice in the last row is after the div of class graybg.  When I publish and surf to the page in Chrome, the rendering is messed up. Inspection with the chrome developer tools shows that selservice follows clmn1 within graybg.  If I remove the line defining "airport_search", the rendering is correct, and the developer tools show selservice following graybg, as it should.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

Change from a self closing tag. I.e.

```
<div id="airport_search" class="imgbtn searchbtn" />
```

to

```
<div id="airport_search" class="imgbtn searchbtn"></div>
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. Do I laugh or cry?

Comment: Hey @RobH can you tell us what's the difference?

Comment: @صفي - self closing tags are valid **x**html (I think there are situations where they don't work) **however** they are not valid html.